# Can I place a 2TB hard drive and a 1 TB hard drive in Raid5?

Tags: windows-10

I have a 2TB hard drive and a 1 TB hard drive that I'd like to put in raid 5. I have a couple questions about this however. Is there any way to preserve the data already on the disk? Can raid treat partitions as logical drives? Also, how to set this up in Windows 10?

Comment: This is more than one question ask one question please., "Can I place a 2TB hard drive and a 1 TB hard drive in Raid5?" yes you can, you should ask what the consequences are.

Comment: RAID5 need more than 2 HDD... (minimum 3 disk)

Comment: I guess a degraded RAID5 could be set up with two disks (never mind the sanity of that unless the third disk is already in the mail).

Comment: If you have a third disk and try to set them up in RAID 5 together you'll be limited to the capacity of the smallest drive. Anything less than 1TB and you'd lose even more potential space, anything over 1TB and you'd be limited to 1TB so it'd be wasted. With that in mind, adding another 1TB drive would be the 'best' simple solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a 2TB hard drive and a 1 TB hard drive that I'd like to put in RAID 5.

RAID 5 needs at least three storage locations. Using two whole drives is not going to do it.

You can partition the 2TB drive (e.g. in two 1TB partitions) and then run something on them, but:

1. It is utterly insane because it will not add the protection you are hoping for. With 3 drives in RAID5 one drive can fail. If you try to fool it with partitions and the 2TB drive fails then you still loose all your data.
2. RAID usally builds on accessing multiple spindles at the same time. With only 2 disks your only have two spindles.
3. And while I state that it is possible for RAID (and I know mdX can do it on Linux), I have no idea how windows will act. Given its nature to 'help' the user from doing silly things it probably forbids it.

> Is there any way to preserve the data already on the disk?

Usually not.  I have a few post about converting a two drive system from plain disk and unused disk to a mdx mirror, but that is highly situational.

> Can RAID  treat partitions as logical drives?

Sure it can. The bigger question is, can your implementation do it. RAID setups itself however have no problem with this.